# Migrate Status on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a problem with my app on Heroku.

When I run

`heroku run rake db:migrate:status`

it shows 5 of my migrations with only 2 of them saying up status and the other 3 three say down status.

How do i get the other three to be up. I ran

`heroku run rake db:migrate`

what step am i missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Those should be the correct steps...  Do the Heroku logs say anything, or do you get any output back from running the `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: I was receiving an error when i tried to do the migrate. I somehow missed it. I was migrating a column that was already there. I was able to fix the problem by doing the following.

This resolved my problem

   " heroku run rake db:setup "

Then

   " heroku run rake db:migrate:reset "

Finally my migrate passes

    " heroku run rake db:migrate "

Then i restarted heroku

    " heroku restart "

My app works as normal